# Can I trigger a CSS event in mobile safari upon iphone orientation change?

Tags: iphone, iphone-web-app

I'm trying to figure out how to change an embedded web page when the user rotates their phone from portrait to landscape mode - basically to load a view that is better suited to the wider screen format. Is this possible to do without calling a new page from the server, i.e. to drive it from within CSS/Javascript itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `window.orientation` property. Its value is the degree that the current mode of view is used. Here is a brief example:

```
function updateOrientation()
{   
    var orientation=window.orientation;
    switch(orientation)
    {

        case 0:

                break;  

        case 90:
                break;

        case -90:   

                break;
    }

}
```

You can use this function on this event:

```
window.onorientationchange=updateOrientation;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 7):

Best not to set the `onorientationchange` property directly. Instead use the following:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function (evt) {
    switch(window.orientation) {
        case 0: // portrait
        case 180: // portrait
        case 90: // landscape
        case -90: // landscape
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 5):

The Safari mobile browser has support for the [`orientationchange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW16) event as well as the `orientation` property on the window, so you can do something like:

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
    switch(window.orientation) {
        case 0:   // Portrait
        case 180: // Upside-down Portrait
            // Javascript to setup Portrait view
            break;
        case -90: // Landscape: turned 90 degrees counter-clockwise
        case 90:  // Landscape: turned 90 degrees clockwise
            // Javascript to steup Landscape view
            break;
    }
}
```

I would add the upside-down because the iPad human interface guidelines say you should support *all* orientations, so I would expect Safari on the iPad (and possibly future iPhone versions) to support it.

Answer (score 5):

I can't believe no one talked about the css ruling:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) // Portait Mode
{
/* CSS RULINGS */
p{}
body{}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 321px) // Landscape Mode
{
/* CSS RULINGS */
p{}
body{}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Safari Mobile supports [orientation events](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW16).

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onorientationchange="updateOrientation();">
```

From: [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)