# Android Emulator: Orientation Change

Tags: android, css, orientation

I was trying to build a simple web page for Android that has two different layouts depending on the orientation. I used the emulator to test the page: Android emulator version 7.0 (build_id OPENMASTER-53891) on Mac.

I tried the CSS [media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693462/mobile-webapp-css-breaks-on-orientation-change) `orientation:` and also the [JavaScript method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313194/can-i-trigger-a-css-event-in-mobile-safari-upon-iphone-orientation-change) but to no avail: when I changed the orientation on the emulator, nothing happened. Is this because of the emulator i.e. the emulator browser doesn't properly work upon orientation change?

Comment: I tried using a newer emulator i.e. Android emulator version 11.0 (build_id OPENMASTER-123211), but still didn't work. :(

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to change orientation of your monitor?

Just kidding :-) Try this combination of keys on your computer:

Switch to previous layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape)    , Ctrl-F11
Switch to next layout orientation (for example, portrait, landscape)    , Ctrl-F12

Comment: That's what I did to change the emulator orientation: Ctrl+Apple+F11. However, nothing changed in terms of the layout / CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create layout and layout-land directories?

And make sure that the activity doesn't have the tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

on the manifest.