# How to say that you need to turn your mobile phone in javascript/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website wich you can only view on a horizontal way.
But i don't know how to block it if it is vertical.
I just can't figure out...
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you considered checking the screen resolution and seeing whether width or height is bigger? Also, why in the world would you create a horrible experience for someone that wants to use the site in portrait?

Comment: because the mobile site is not totaly finished

Comment: @joske_saalfeld that's not a compelling reason to do what you're asking. It sounds likely that the existing css is inflexible and not exactly responsive - maybe not even "appropriate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in CSS by hiding/showing dependant on orientation

```
<style type="text/css">
    #warning-message { display: none; }
    @media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
        #wrapper { display:none; }
        #warning-message { display:block; }
    }
    @media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
        #warning-message { display:none; }
    }
</style>

....

<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- your html for your website -->
</div>
<div id="warning-message">
    this website is only viewable in landscape mode
</div>
```

SOURCE [forcing web-site to show in landscape mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738072/forcing-web-site-to-show-in-landscape-mode-only)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, [this](https://gist.github.com/visnup/2605440) might help. I do suggest against it though, as there is currently isn't a very clean way to do it, and it can be user-unfriendly.

Comment: no because here you can't tell why this happens