# Lock screen orientation for all mobile devices (browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-orientation

I am looking for a way to lock the screen orientation to landscape for all mobile device browsers when accessing a website. I couldn't get a clear result when searching cause it always gives results for app creating and locking but not for websites.

Apparently this "kinda" (it does rotate the entire website but it keeps the width of portrait mode) works for Android but not at all in IOS..even in android isn't perfect:

```
/* if portrait mode is detected, rotate the entire site -90 degrees to hint rotating to landscape */
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I really don't see that happening.

Comment: @Kriggs check my update

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738072/forcing-web-site-to-show-in-landscape-mode-only

Answer (score 2):

You can force the width using:

```
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    width:100vh;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, vh isn't supported apparently at the moment so i get the same result, the website width is equivalent to it's width on portrait mode.

Comment: I meant by my android device :) I tried it  and only afterwards i replied.

Comment: Well for those **older devices** you can adjust the width using JS.