# forcefully change window orientation to landscape

Tags: jquery, html, orientation

i want orientation to be landscape, when my website is open in mobile and it must locks on landscape.

i tried some code as below, but it is not working as desired

```
function rotate(degrees) {
    $('body').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
    });
};
$(window).on("orientationchange", function(event) {
    if (window.orientation == 0) {} else {
        rotate(-90);
    }
});
$(window).orientationchange();
```

Answer (score 0):

check this, already answered a similar question

[forcing web-site to show in landscape mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738072/forcing-web-site-to-show-in-landscape-mode-only)

I'd prefer to use CSS and CSS3 media queries rather than the JavaScript for such case.

Comment: i want to rotate to landscape. don't want to hide the content.

Comment: i give same problem as my code gives, menus get's open and other problem, view come as desktop

Comment: using `transform` is not a good idea because some web browsers do not support for it specially mobile browsers