# how to lock ipad orientation in landscape for mobile webapps

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, css

can anyone tel how to lock ipad orientation in landscape for mobile webapps. even if it flip it should not rotate into portrait.

```
     function reorient(e) {
        var portrait = (window.orientation % 180 != 0);
        $("body").css("-webkit-transform", !portrait ? "rotate(90deg)" : "");
        alert("hi");
      } 
       window.onorientationchange = reorient;
       window.setTimeout(reorient, 0)
```

i tried these code but it affecting only the design . where as in my case it should flip

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806938/is-there-a-way-to-force-horizontal-landscape-layout-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 0):

You could control the CSS in both orientations with a media query

```
media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)
```

Lèse majesté wrote a good answer to this question here which involves countering the rotation with jquery: [Blocking device rotation on mobile web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages)

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange resize', function(event){
  if(event.orientation) {
    if (event.orientation == 'landscape') {
      if (window.rotation == 90) {
        rotate(this, -90);
      } else {
        rotate(this, 90);
      }
    }
  });

function rotate(el, degs) {
  iedegs = degs/90;
  if (iedegs < 0) iedegs += 4);
  transform = 'rotate('+degs+'deg)';
  iefilter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation='+iedegs+')';
  styles = {
    transform: transform,
    '-webkit-transform': transform,
    '-moz-transform': transform,
    '-o-transform': transform,
    filter: iefilter,
    '-ms-filter': iefilter
  };
  $(el).css(styles);
}
```