# How to fix jquerymobile web application orientation to landscape

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How can I fix my jquerymobile web application orientation to landscape. My application looks perfect in landscape mode so I strictly wants to display application in landscape mode. If user rotate the device, then application display mode should not be change to portrait.

How can I do it. Any web link or source code would be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer. You can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. Hope it is usefull though. Didn't try it.

[Link to other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806938/is-there-a-way-to-force-horizontal-landscape-layout-on-mobile-devices)