# Website on Mobile Device Renders "The Wide Way"

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I feel like I recently got a hold on HTML and CSS.  If it were 1998 I would be feeling great.  Unfortunately, I need to understand better how mobile phones and tablets are going to render my site.

I was wondering if it were possible to force devices to render the web "the wide way." For example, iPhones, if turned, will render the material "the wide way" (hopefully you understand the title now).  I would like to FORCE that, so the user is forced to turn their phone in order to look at the content.

Is there a way to do that? A simple javascript maybe?

Thanks,
Pat

Comment: Check out this accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806938/is-there-a-way-to-force-horizontal-landscape-layout-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 0):

The correct term for "The Wide Way" would be "Landscape".

Unfortunately you cannot force the website to render as a landscape, but you could force the user to view a modal that does not close unless you rotate your phone. (You could do this via media queries)

[This user posted a solution to this very question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8738200/2574944)