# How to make site show always in Portrait orientation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a mobile site, and i need it to show screen as it always was in portrait orientation. Like Instagram app. works.

How could i do this with codes ?

```
if (window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90) {
   window.orientation=0;
}
```

Comment: You can't lock the orientation.

Comment: [Someone has run into something slightly similar.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806938/is-there-a-way-to-force-horizontal-landscape-layout-on-mobile-devices/4807047#4807047) But honestly, actually making a responsive design is a lot better than gettin' real hacky with it.

Comment: I didn't understand what u want. Do you want your website get turned to 90° ? Or you want it to show with low width and long height  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a good idea in general but you can find discussion here :

[Blocking device rotation on mobile web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages)

[How do I lock the orientation to portrait mode in a iPhone Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application)

a solution could be to **rotate** the content using CSS3 on orientation **change event**.