# Force HTML5 app to be in landscape mode

Tags: android, ios, html, windows-phone-8

I am creating a simple HTML5/CSS3/Javascript app which will work on all 3 platforms android/ios/windows-phone. But I want it to be in landscape mode only even if the mobile is held upright. Anyway I can achieve it?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806938/is-there-a-way-to-force-horizontal-landscape-layout-on-mobile-devices/4807047#4807047

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html) use this

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```