# Can you change what is displayed when orientation is changed in safari for iOS?

Tags: iphone, css, ios, safari

I have a mobile website, which currently displays a timetable. The non-mobile site however also has a iFrame with google maps inside it, to display multiple vehicles being tracked.

For the mobile site, I want only the timetable to display in portrait and only the iframe to display in landscape.

I've seen this [Can I trigger a CSS event in mobile safari upon iphone orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313194/can-i-trigger-a-css-event-in-mobile-safari-upon-iphone-orientation-change) , but I struggle to see how I can apply this to my query.

This is the CSS for the iFrame:

```
.map {
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #888;
  box-shadow: inner 0 0 5px #888;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: do you know Javascript? you need to use javascript to hide the content depending on the orientation

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Javascript to hide content in web pages

Comment: the question that you linked is using Javascript. That's probably why you are struggling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `@media`

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media all and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

Don't abuse javascript when CSS can do it.

[`orientation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation)

Answer (score 3):

First you will need to assign ID to your timetable container and iFrame. Then, use the javascript below to hide or display it. I will assume that your iFrame id is `'map'` and your timetable container is `'timetable'`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timetable = document.getElementById('timetable');
var map = document.getElementById('map').

window.onorientationchange = function() {
    switch(window.orientation) {
        case 0:   // Portrait
        case 180: // Upside-down Portrait
            // Javascript to setup Portrait view
            timetable.style.display = 'none';
            map.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case -90: // Landscape: turned 90 degrees counter-clockwise
        case 90:  // Landscape: turned 90 degrees clockwise
            // Javascript to steup Landscape view
            timetable.style.display = 'none';
            map.style.display = 'block';
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `language` is deprecated. Use `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: @Raynos ow didn't know ... I normally just put `<script></script>` haha.. thanks

Comment: Don't use JavaScript when you can just use `@media` queries.